# node ffmpeg module stuck more than one file

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

when I read more than one file it will be stuck and also hang my pc. I need to restart my pc

on one file or 5 files it will work perfectly but not more than 5 files

if anyone know this issue let me know

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)


const testFolder = './videos/';
const fs = require('fs');

 


fs.readdir(testFolder, async(err, files) => {
  try {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if(files[i] != '1 Surah Fatiha Dr Israr Ahmed Urdu - 81of81.mp4'){
        
        let converter = await ffmpeg(`./videos/${files[i]}`)
        await converter.setStartTime('00:00:00').setDuration('30').output(`./outputfolder/${files[i]}`).on('end', function(err) {
        if(err) { 
          console.log(`err durinng conversation \n ${err}`) 
        }
        else{
          console.log(`Done ${files[i]}`);
        }
        }).on('error', function(err){
          console.log(`error: ${files[i]}`, err)
        }).run()
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is crashing because `fluent-ffmpeg` is not asynchronous, this makes your code run in a loop running `ffmpeg` several times without waiting for the previous video to complete processing, consequently consuming all your processing power.

I created an asynchronous function called `renderVideo` and changed the `for` loop to the `for of` loop, as only it is able to wait for an asynchronous function.

The code looked like this:

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
const fs = require('fs');

const testFolder = './videos/';

fs.readdir(testFolder, async(err, videos) => {
  try {
    for(let video of videos){
      if(video != '1 Surah Fatiha Dr Israr Ahmed Urdu - 81of81.mp4'){
         await renderVideo(video)
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  
   function renderVideo(video){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         let converter = ffmpeg(`./videos/${video}`)
         
         converter
         .setStartTime('00:00:00')
         .setDuration('30')
         .output(`./outputfolder/${video}`)
         .on('end', (done)=> {
            resolve(done)
         })
         .on('error', (err)=> {
            reject(`The video ${video} return with error: ${err}`)
         })
         .run()
      })
   }
})
```

I also changed the names of some variables to make sense in the current code.

Comment: Glad I could help, when possible, please mark the answer as resolved. I thank!